# How can I get script after end of <html> tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags

Have something like this:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body></body>
</html>

<script id="ajaxify-data" type="application/json">
  ....
<script>
```

How can I get this script element? 
All DOM functions like `$("#ajaxify-data")`, `document.getElementByID("#ajaxify-data")` dont work

P.S.: I saw this script on this [site](https://discuss.leetcode.com/unread). But I can`t get it in the consolt? Is it possible?

Comment: where/how are you running that code, and did you actually load the jquery library?

Comment: Just don't place `script` tags outside of the `html` and `head`/`body` tags. This is invalid.

Comment: `document.scripts(document.scripts.length - 1)` dont work.

Comment: Do you have the correct timing? It's not there, if you're retrieving the collection too early.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it.
If you need to get the script after end of html tag. You only need to get this html by the ajax as a json and parce this one to with regular expression.

Its a bad but single way.

Answer (score 1):

Please, note that any element outside < /html > tag is not rendered, is not a valid logic to put any element of a webpage outside of what it is considered the end of a webpage. If you paste your code in https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input you will receive the error "document type does not allow element SCRIPT here".

So, it is fine if you put your SCRIPT right before the closing  tag. A $(body).append() function will work.

Comment: A script tag outside of the head/body tags is not valid either. The permitted contents of an HTML tag is [One head element, followed by one body element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/html.html#html-content-model).